# How to convert BigDecimal into f64?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I have a SQL query that returns a column with the `BigDecimal` type but my domain model works with `f64`:

```
price: Price::new(record.price).unwrap(),
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  rustc: mismatched types 
                     expected `f64`, found struct `BigDecimal`
```

How can I convert `BigDecimal` type into `f64`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by following steps

1. Add bigdecimal crate to the project (`cargo add bigdecimal`)
2. Add `use bigdecimal::ToPrimitive;` to the top of the file where I want to convert types.
3. use `.to_f64()` method on my `BigDecimal` instance

```
use bigdecimal::ToPrimitive;

...
price: Price::new(record.price.to_f64().unwrap()).unwrap()
...
```

The [`to_f64()`](https://docs.rs/bigdecimal/latest/bigdecimal/trait.ToPrimitive.html#method.to_f64-4) method appeared on the `BigDecimal` type